# AutoMapper Lazy Load Maps

Tags: automapper

I have a ton of domain entity to dto maps, that are basically one to one maps like this:

```
CreateMap<Package, PackageForm>();
```

I have to call `CreateMap` for each map, this seems like it could be handled by a convention or something. Is it possible to have AutoMapper (try to) create a mapping on the fly when `Map()` is called for a non-existing map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just discovered `Mapper.DynamicMap()`, seems to be what I was after.

Comment: Just keep in mind you'll lose the ability to validate your maps with DynamicMap.

Comment: Thanks, I have some tests to cover that.